# What is a good API to setup user to user payments in an Android app?

Tags: android, api, online-payment, kotlin

I am making an Android app with Kotlin and AWS where users will be able to directly make payments to one another for various products/services. For now I want those payments to be through credit cards with a small fee going to the developers. I am looking for a convenient API to accomplish this. I've looked into Google Pay, Stripe Connect and Smart2Pay. What would you recommend me to use? It doesn't have to be any of the ones I've mentioned. Also some guides are welcome on how to accomplish this are always welcome as I've never tried to setup a payment system in an Android app.

Comment: I think you cannot send money to a credit card in general. In my country it works like a refund but not as a means of getting paid. I would look at some abstraction to make payments between two parties, for example if every one of them has an account with GitHub or some other common platform, use that API, but involving 2 or more currencies is almost worse than a cryptocurrency transaction. In EU, a SEPA payment is usually fast and free of charge, but regulations vary